# sort function not working correctly

Tags: c++, sorting

When I use the sort function in the algorithm library, it does not seem to be working correctly. I'm trying to display my newly sorted array but it is just displaying the array the way it was entered and not sorted.

```
sort(user_list, user_list +1);
cout<< "\nLISt in sorted order"<< endl;
display_list(user_list, list_size);
```

It also may be worth noting there are zero errors showing up in my code right now. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what type is `user_list`?

Comment: Don't tag both [tag:c++] and [tag:c].

Comment: @vu1p3n0x char type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sort(user_list, user_list +1);
```

isn't going to do anything, algorithms take the start and one past-the-end, In effect you are saying to sort zero elements. Add the correct size instead of 1.

Comment: its actually sorting one element, not zero, but the same effect because a single element is already sorted